# How can I delete the last word in the current line, but only if a pattern occurs on the next line?

Tags: regex, awk, sed

The contents of the file are

```
some line DELETE_ME
some line this_is_the_pattern
```

If the `this_is_the_pattern` occurs in the *next* line, then delete the last word (in this case `DELETE_ME`) in the current line.

How can I do this using sed or awk? My understanding is that sed is more appropriate for this task than awk is, because awk is suitable for operations on data stored tabular format. If my understanding is incorrect, please let me know.

Comment: Your understanding is incorrect. sed is for simple substitutions on individual lines, certainly not for anything involving analyzing/changing multiple lines simultaneously. awk is for everything else. All of seds arcane language constructs for trying to do things across input lines became obsolete in the mid-1970s when awk was invented, people just play with them today mostly for the challenge/mental exercise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 awk 'NR>1 && /this_is_the_pattern/ {print t;}
      NR>1 && !/this_is_the_pattern/ {print f;}
      {f=$0;$NF="";t=$0}
      END{print f}' input-file
```

Note that this will modify whitespace in any lines in which the last field is removed, squeezing runs of whitespace into a single space.

You could simplify this to:

```
awk 'NR>1 { print( /this_is_the_pattern/? t:f)}
      {f=$0;$NF="";t=$0}
      END{print f}' input-file
```

and you can resolve the squeezed whitespace issue with:

```
awk 'NR>1 { print( /this_is_the_pattern/? t:f)}
      {f=$0;sub(" [^ ]*$","");t=$0}
      END{print f}' input-file
```

Comment: Could you please explain the logic. The confusing part is the the "first and second line" of awk statement are independent of each other.

Comment: The third line of the script stores the full line in f and the truncated line in t.  The first two lines print the appropriate value for the previous line.  The end block prints the last line.

Comment: The code is elegant. I am accepting this because it deals with preserving whitespace.

Answer (score 2):

```
$ awk '/this_is_the_pattern/{sub(/[^[:space:]]+$/, "", last)} NR>1{print last} {last=$0} END{print last}' file
some line
some line this_is_the_pattern
```

#### How it works

This script uses a single variable called `last` which contains the previous line in the file.  In summary, if the current line contains the pattern, then the last word is removed from `last`.  Otherwise, `last` is printed as is.

In detail, taking each command in turn:

- `/this_is_the_pattern/{sub(/[^[:space:]]+$/, "", last)}`

  If this line has the pattern, remove the final word from the last line.
- `NR>1{print last}`

  For each line after the first line, print the last line.
- `last=$0`

  Save the current line in variable `last`.
- `END{print last}`

  Print the last line from the file.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. But i am accepting the other answer because it has a solution which preserves whitespace.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `tac` to cat the file backwards, so that you see the pattern first. Then set a flag and delete the last word on the next line you see. Then at the end, reverse the file through `tac` back to the original order.

```
tac file | awk '/this_is_the_pattern/{f=1;print;next} f==1{sub(/ [^ ]+$/, "");print;f=0}' | tac
```

Comment: Wow. This is really out of box thinking. But i am accepting the other answer because it preserves the white space characters.

Answer (score 1):

Use buffer to keep previous line in memory

```
sed -n 'H;1h;1!{x;/\nPAGE/ s/[^ ]*\(\n\)/\1/;P;s/.*\n//;h;$p;}' YourFile
```

Use loop but same concept

```
sed -n ':cycle
N;/\nPAGE/ s/[^ ]*\(\n\)/\1/;P;s/.*\n//;$p;b cycle' YourFile
```

in both case, it remove last word of previous line also the search pattern is on 2 consecutive lines

work with 2 last read lines, test if pattern on last and delete word if present than print first line, remove it and cycle

Answer (score 1):

The idiomatic awk solution is simply to keep a buffer of the previous line (or N lines in the general case) so you can test the current line and then modify and/or print the buffer accordingly:

```
$ awk '
    NR>1 {
        if (/this_is_the_pattern/) {
            sub(/[^[:space:]]+$/,"",prev)
        }
        print prev
    }
    { prev = $0 }
    END { print prev }
' file
some line
some line this_is_the_pattern
```